# How would you go about modeling a hood for this jacket mesh?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, geometry

[image: Jacket mesh]

Hello, I'm trying to add a hood to this jacket mesh I made and was wondering about how others would approach the problem.

To clarify, I'm wanting to have this hood in a rest position, not raised. I've got a good idea of how to model it in a raised position it is at rest that I can't really get my head around.

---

My first idea was to create an extrusion along the back faces of the collar, and then shape it further, and remove the top most faces from it.

[image: extrusion selection.]
[image: extrusion]

Do you have a better method?

Blend file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtM_pc3Q-xDugR1UMQL-KmORvpPU?e=2wimNf

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could begin by extruding an edge on the back (side view):

[image]

Then fill the gaps, deform, add some extrusions on the side toward the front:

[image]